# Not able to get value from NSUserDefault

Tags: iphone, nsuserdefaults

I am just used below code to store array into userdefault

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:artists forKey:@"test"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and then if we retrieve the data from below code

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
artists = [defaults objectForKey:@"test"];
```

but I am not able to get the data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: does you `artists` parameter not nil when you set it to `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 1):

What does the array contain?  Only certain types of content can be encoded into NSUserDefaults.  The array must be able to be converted to a plist.  The doc for [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary.